# Difference between @ and @@ in Less

Tags: css, less

I'm new to LESS and I see variables defined 2 different ways.  It's hard to research special characters on Google so I'm struggling to find the answer.

```
@@width: 10px;
```

vs:

```
@width: 10px;
```

Which one is correct or what's the difference?

Comment: Have you looked at the [Less documentation](https://lesscss.org/features/)?

Comment: You can type "LESS @@" into Google and it will search just fine.

Comment: @Sean Yes I saw that documentation but couldn't understand

Comment: https://lesscss.org/features/#variables-feature-variable-variables - this section tells you what the difference is. It's not a matter of correct, the `@@` is essentially using another variable's value. However, in your example, the syntax is wrong for the first one. It should be `@width: 10px` and then you would use that value in a later selector like `width: @@width`